# html area map shape rect not showing

Tags: html

I copied the exact code for html area map from w3schools
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap

When i view source on above page i see

```
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">
```

but when i copy exact same code on my site **shape="rect"** disappears and i only see this

```
<area coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">
```

This is happening only for rectangular shape for poly and circle it works fine.

Comment: How are you posting the code to your site? FTP, or some interactive editor?

Comment: I am uploading page by SFTP and if add any other character/no after rect then shape starts showing like if i write shape="rect0" then after uploading in view source its shows shape="rect0"